# How to Create DDL in HIVE and save it as a file in your directory

Tags: hive, hiveql

Currently, I use the following code to show the DDL of tables in HIVE:

```
Show create table cus_data
```

I'm trying to write the results of that statement to a file in a given location on my command line. I tried the following but to no avail:

```
hive>  show create table  -f  “home/e13/sample_file”
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
hive -e "show create table cus_data" > ~/output.txt
```